# Why only a part of my child React component is showing up in the parent React component?

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I have a parent component that is using a child component which is like this:-

```
class Seasonal extends React.Component{


    componentDidMount(){

        const container = document.querySelector(".container");
        const lefty = document.querySelector(".lefty");
        let translate = 0;

        lefty.addEventListener("click", function() {
            translate += 200;
            container.style.transform = "translateX(" + translate + "px" + ")";
        });

        const righty = document.querySelector(".righty");
        righty.addEventListener("click", function() {
            translate -= 200;
            container.style.transform = "translateX(" + translate + "px" + ")";
        });

    }


    render() {
        return(
                <div>                   

                    <button class="lefty paddle" id="left-button"></button>
                    <div class="outer" id="content" >
                      <div class="container">
                        <div class="inner" style={{background:'red'}}></div>
                        <div class="inner" style={{background:'red'}}></div>
                        <div class="inner" style={{background:'red'}}></div>
                        <div class="inner" style={{background:'red'}}></div>
                        <div class="inner" style={{background:'red'}}></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="righty paddle" id="right-button"></button>

                </div>
        )
    }


}
export default Seasonal
```

The css for that is like this:-

```
.outer {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;

}

.inner {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  height: 100px;
  margin:10px;
}
.paddle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 30px;
    height:20px;
}

.lefty {
    left: 0;
}
.righty{
    right: 0;
}
```

When I use it in the parent component only the buttons get displayed the "outer" div is not visible what is the reason?The outer div if I click on inspect element seems to be existing at the top of the page somewhere but its not visible.

Comment: can you show the parent component code

Comment: parent is super huge ..i placed it in swveral places doesnt change

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<div class="container">` and then try... the `<div class="inner">` are the flex child items and need to be to directly below the flex parent item `<div class="outer" id="content">`

edit: this is totally a CSS issue, not a react issue.